# Prove that a poset is totally ordered

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this exercise in [Math LibreText](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/A_Spiral_Workbook_for_Discrete_Mathematics_(Kwong)/07%3A_Relations/7.04%3A_Partial_and_Total_Ordering) while learning about partial & total order.

[image]

I thought of using Benzout's Identity here (though that will be introduced to us soon) such that $gcd(m,n)=1$ → $ma + nb = 1$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. But I don't know how to continue after that. Any help or tips on this proof please?

Comment: In your question, you could list the axioms that a totally ordered set must satisfy, and then prove it satisfies whichever ones you can.  Then someone can easily show you how to do the rest.  At the moment it is not clear which are obvious to you and which need to be explained.  Also, for the ones you cannot do, state what needs to be deduced, given what data.

Comment: @tkf I know that the partial order has to be antisymmetric, reflexive, and transitive. However, I'm not entirely sure how to show that all elements are comparable with each other to say that it's totally ordered.

Comment: OK so that is four things you need to prove.  Write down exactly what you need to prove in each case.  For example, to show any elements $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are comparable you need to show that any natural numbers $a,b,c,d$ satisfy ......

Comment: @tkf So I just officially learned partial & total order in class, however we didn't tackle much about proof writing, only the Hasse diagrams. What I did learn for total order is that it must satisfy $ad≤bc$ or $bc≤ad$ for this question, but I'm not sure exactly how to continue the proof when starting it with your hint.

Comment: Great - that is correct.  But for any natural numbers  $x,y$ you know $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$ so you are done: just let $x=ad$ and $y=bc$.  Now move on to showing it is reflexive: for any natural numbers $a,b$ we have ....

Comment: So reflexivity helps prove the relation to be totally ordered? I understand it now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: We use the fact that the naturals are totally ordered to prove that all elements are comparable under this relation.  Reflexivity, anti-symmetry and transitivity need to be proven separately to show that we have a total order.  To show something is a total order there are 4 separate exercises you need to do.  You have done one, but you still need to do the other 3  (Reflexivity, anti-symmetry and transitivity).